# Create additional Edges when subdividing

Tags: edges, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

When I make clothing and subdivide one piece that I am going to sew together with some other piece, I want addtional edges to be created.

So, suppose I have this:

[image: Demonstration]

In that case, I dont want it to be transformed like this:

[image: Demonstration]

But rather like this:

[image: Demonstration]

Is there any one or two clicks solution to this?
If there isn't, I would also be thankful for relevant API references, so I could maybe write an add-on that does exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but couldn't you just (only) select the faces you want subdivided and subdivide those (instead of the whole object)?

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem, because it won't create any new sewing edges. In the end, every vertex on right side for example has to be connected to the corresponding vertex of the other plane by edges, as you can see in image 3, which is my desired outcome. When you are just subdividing, there will be vertices in the middle that are not connected, as you can see in image 2.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think I get it - You want to subdivide the faces and create new edge connections around the "borders", without subdividing the edge connections themselves. Is that close?

Comment: Yes, that is a pretty perfect description! I figured out a very unconvinient way one could approach this: make a plane -> subdivide it -> copy it -> select the "border vertices" of both the original and the copy -> use the tool bridge edge loops and then delete only the faces.

Comment: Yeah. I've been trying a few different things, but I can't find any sort of "automatic" way to do it. I'll upvote the question - maybe someone who knows a better way will come by and shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't really find an existing solution that satisfied my requirements, so I wrote a script that does exactly what is descripted in this post.
You can get it [here](https://therigid.gumroad.com/l/ZlZuC).

Edit: The add-on should still work, but I remember there were some limitations with the simple algorithm I have used, so it might not do anything in your specific case.

Comment: Is this script available anywhere? the gumroad link is dead

Comment: @Greg: Apologies for the dead link, replaced it. I hope this is still useful!

Comment: @GregMckechnie <-- to notify the real Greg Mckechnie